# Is it possible to filter the Connect API on users that are CC'ed but not the sender?

Tags: docusignapi

I am building a service that will use DocuSign Connect to capture specific completed envelopes and push them to our back-end document management system. I have been able to get DocuSign to post events when the sender is selected in "Associated Users" but I would ideally like to only listen on a specific user that would be CC'ed on only the templates we would like to capture instead of getting all events. I have tried selecting only the user that will be CC and I do not get any events.
Is it possible to get events based on accounts that are CC'ed? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, Stack overflow is not a code writing service.  Please make an attempt to solve your problem in the coding language of your choice (none is listed) and we can help you solve any problems that you might encounter along the way.  For more information, please visit the help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using [eventNotifications](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#webhooks), which use the DocuSign Connect engine but are configured at the envelope level.

DocuSign Connect provides a GUI that lets you configure all your webhooks across the account, event notifications are configured on a per envelope basis and are more granular.